# Divide DataFrame Column on (,) into two new columns

Tags: python, pandas, explode

I have a pandas DataFrame called data_combined with the following structure:

```
    index   corr_year   corr_5d
0   (DAL, AAL)  0.873762    0.778594
1   (WEC, ED)   0.851578    0.850549
2   (CMS, LNT)  0.850028    0.776143
3   (SWKS, QRVO)    0.850799    0.830603
4   (ALK, DAL)  0.874162    0.744590
```

Now I am trying to divide the column named index into two columns on the (,).
The desired output should look like this:

```
    index1  index2   corr_year  corr_5d
0   DAL    AAL   0.873762   0.778594
1   WEC    ED    0.851578   0.850549
2   CMS    LNT   0.850028   0.776143
3   SWKS   QRVO  0.850799   0.830603
4   ALK    DAL   0.874162   0.744590
```

I have tried using pd.explode() with the following code

```
data_results_test = data_results_combined.explode('index')
data_results_test
```

Which leads to the following output:

```
    index   corr_year   corr_5d
0   DAL 0.873762    0.778594
0   AAL 0.873762    0.778594
1   WEC 0.851578    0.850549
1   ED  0.851578    0.850549
```

How can I achieve the split with newly added columns instead of rows. pd.explode does not seem to have any option to choose wether to add new rows or columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple apply? (Assuming 'index' column is a tuple)

```
data_results_combined['index1'] = data_results_combined['index'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
data_results_combined['index2'] = data_results_combined['index'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['index1','index2']] = df['index'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Comment: I tried your answer however I am getting the error: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
Which is weird because the length of the data frame is 96 x 3 so there is no column longer than the other

Comment: You may be having a col name dupe/collision. As best practice I try not to use 'index' as a col name since sometimes pandas internals wants to use it when trying to preserve the numbered/named index during operations.